# How to lexicographicly enumerate unordered pairs of integers

Tags: algorithm, indexing, combinatorics

what is the algorithm (or rather formula) which, for each pair integers i and j with j >= i, gives an integer k = k(i,j) such that

- k(0,0) = 0
- k(i,j2) = k(i,j1)+1 for j2 = j1 + 1
- k(i,0) = k(i-1,i-1) + 1  , i >= 1

holds?

In other words, if you fill up the left-lower part of matrix row by row from left to right with the natural numbers, starting at 0, how can you compute the value of a cell given the index of its row i and the column index j <= i?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks. *starts to unblockhead*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proof of Alleo answer:

first write your second formula from j to 1

```
k(i,j)= k(i,j-1) + 1
k(i,j-1) = k(i,j-2) + 1
...
k(i,1) = k(i,0) + 1
```

sum up these formulas you get :

```
k(i,j) = k(i,0) + 1+1 ..+1 = k(i,0) + j  (1)
```

now from your 3rd formula:

```
k(i,0) = k(i-1,i-1) + 1
```

using (1) :

```
k(i-1,i-1) = k(i-1,0) + i-1
```

then

```
k(i,0) = k(i-1,0) + i
```

then since k(0,0) = 0

```
k(i,0) = sum(p for p=0 to i) = i*(i+1)/2 (2)
```

then

```
(1) & (2) => k(i,j) = i*(i+1)/2 + j
```

Answer (score 1):

This is i*(i+1)/2 + j. You are welcome to check